# correct fourier transform of time series starting with different start/end times

Tags: fourier-transform, dft, time-series

I have lots of time series where I want to analyse some periodic signal that occurs beside the signal I wanted to measure (and I didn't expect). The idea is that there's always a peak at a certain frequency. The problem is they have different start and end times `[start, end]`. Start can be negative (0 has a special meaning) and sometimes most of the data is in the negative part, so I can't just crop it. I am a bit unsure how to proceed. I know that there's a cyclic property of dft so I don't think I can just naively dft it. Maybe some kind of zero-padding so that there's no overlap? I also don't know how to calculate the frequencies after the shift. They don't seem to match anymore, but I need to compare the time-series so I need comparable frequencies.

I am mostly interested in a low-frequency period, which I want to compare between those samples.

Comment: Are you trying to do pitch or frequency detection? There are plenty of algorithms for that and DFT is not necessarily the best one, but that depends a lot on your specific data and application.

Comment: I think I didn't express myself very good. I will edit the question. I suspect that in addition to the signal I wanted to measure, there's a periodic signal present which I want to analyse and see whether it's present in all measurements.